# Custom component not repeating but being replaced

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, ngfor

I have create a custom component in my angular 6 application, this component is called QuizComponent.

On my HomePage (another component) I instantiate multiple instances of QuizComponent in the middle of my HTML code which simplified can be seen as something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <img [src]="item.url">
   <quiz [questions]="item.questions"></quiz>
<div>
```

As a result, the images are displayed fine (unique ones) however only a single quiz is displayed and that represents the last one in the items list.
It seems that my component is being instantiated only once, even inside the ngFor.

How can I have one instance of my QuizComponent for each loop interaction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide a stackblitz demo here https://stackblitz.com/ and edit your code snippet with the all components

Comment: can you post your `items`?